# Weird error with syntax

Tags: z3, smt, satisfiability

Just experimenting with smtlib.  I'm not seeing whats wrong with the following...

```
(set-logic BV)
(declare-fun var1 () (_ BitVec 32)) ; a is a constant
(declare-fun var2 () (_ BitVec 32)) ; a is a constant
(declare-fun var3 () (_ BitVec 32)) ; a is a constant

(assert(
    (= var1 var2)
    and
    (= var3 bvsub(var1 var2) )
    ))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Running it with z3 and the error is:
(error "line 7 column 2: invalid qualified/indexed identifier, '_' or 'as' expected")

Comment: The problem is Z3's input syntax is in prefix notation ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation ), which you have for the equalities (e.g., `(= var1 var2)`, but not some of the other parts (e.g., `a and b`), where you are using infix notation ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation ).

Answer (score 1):

2 edits later, finally figured it out:

```
(set-logic BV)
(declare-fun var1 () (_ BitVec 32)) ; a is a constant
(declare-fun var2 () (_ BitVec 32)) ; a is a constant
(declare-fun var3 () (_ BitVec 32)) ; a is a constant

(assert(
    and (= var1 var2) (= var3 (bvsub var1 var2))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```